# Use a single where clause in mySQL statement with 2 subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

I have a mySQL query, which works fine. All of the subquery where clauses specify the same time as the main statement where clause, however I need to use the where clause from the main statement, in my sub queries. Is this possible? My current query is:

```
SELECT
"Total" as "Total",
sum(case when  s.stage = 'Main Stage' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Main Stage',
sum(case when  s.stage = 'Secondary Stage' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Secondary Stage',
    (SELECT count(distinct t.ticket_number) FROM events e
    join stages s on e.stage_id = o.id
    join tickets t on t.id = e.ticket_id
    where s.stage = 'Third Stage' 
    and e.started > '2018-03-10 00:00:00' and e.started < '2018-03-10 13:25:00') - 
        (SELECT count(distinct t.ticket_number) FROM events e
        join stages s on e.stage_id = o.id
        join tickets t on t.id = e.ticket_id
        where s.stage = 'Fourth Stage'
        and e.started > '2018-03-10 00:00:00' and e.started < '2018-03-10 13:25:00'
        ) as 'Other Stages'
FROM events e
join stages s on e.stage_id = o.id
join tickets t on t.id = e.ticket_id
where  e.started > '2018-03-10 00:00:00' and e.started < '2018-03-10 13:25:00'
```

The query I am looking for: 
I have a mySQL query, which works fine. All of the subquery where clauses specify the same time as the main statement where clause, however I need to use the where clause from the main statement, in my sub queries. Is this possible? My current query is:

```
SELECT
"Total" as "Total",
sum(case when  s.stage = 'Main Stage' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Main Stage',
sum(case when  s.stage = 'Secondary Stage' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Secondary Stage',
    (SELECT count(distinct t.ticket_number) FROM events e
    join stages s on e.stage_id = o.id
    join tickets t on t.id = e.ticket_id
    where s.stage = 'Third Stage') - 
        (SELECT count(distinct t.ticket_number) FROM events e
        join stages s on e.stage_id = o.id
        join tickets t on t.id = e.ticket_id
        where s.stage = 'Fourth Stage'
        ) as 'Other Stages'
FROM events e
join stages s on e.stage_id = o.id
join tickets t on t.id = e.ticket_id
where  e.started > '2018-03-10 00:00:00' and e.started < '2018-03-10 13:25:00'
```

But I need the subqueries to still search by time, otherwise the data isn't correct. The reason I need to do this is related to private framework issues.
Sample results:
[image]

Comment: Why? Is it just because you wish to reuse some of the SQL?

Comment: @PeterM For the technology I am using its dynamic, so I basically pass in two datetime strings, but this query needs 6 datetime strings, I just need to make it so the entire query uses one set of time parameters, passed in once

Comment: Then why not use a [Prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)?

Comment: @PeterM I am but for the example I just put in times just to make it easier to understand where I'm going with it (probably should have said that), but I can only pass in the date and time once

Comment: Then try setting that `datetime` into a [MySQL variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) and use that multiple times inside your query.